# separate print to PDF by ID with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf

I want to print my Access 2010 report for each ID.

Lets say my report structure is like this:

```
ID1,    Name1,    phone1,   address1,

ID1,    Name2,    phone2,   address2,

ID2,    Name,    phone,   address,

ID3,    Name1,    phone1,   address1,

ID3,    Name2,    phone2,   address2,
```

What I want is for each ID to be written to a separate .pdf file like this:

ID1.pdf contains:

```
ID1,    Name1,    phone1,   address1,

ID1,    Name2,    phone2,   address2,
```

ID2.pdf contains:

```
ID2,    Name,    phone,   address,
```

ID3.pdf contains:

```
ID3,    Name1,    phone1,   address1,

ID3,    Name2,    phone2,   address2,
```

I created the following code:

```
Private Sub PrintPDF_Click()

Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim OutputFile As String
Dim FileSavePath As String

FileSavePath = "C:\Test\"
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT distinct ID FROM Report_Query ORDER BY _ID")
With rst
Do Until .EOF

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, Bericht1, acFormatPDF, FileSavePath & ![ID] & ".pdf", True

.MoveNext

Loop

End With

End Sub
```

Naming has worked well, but it prints all records.  I have ID1.pdf, ID2.pdf, and ID3.pdf but each file contains all the records.

How can I produce one file per ID?

Comment: Inside the recordset loop - open report filtered to single ID, output the report, close report, move to next record, open report filtered to single ID, output report, close report, move ...

Comment: you can execute query for every id. like `SELECT distinct ID FROM Report_Query Where ID = 'ID1' ORDER BY _ID`

Comment: you have the outer loop, which iterates all the IDs. before the `DoCmd.OutputTo ...` line, put another query. something like `select data that i want from report_query where ID = rst.ID`  .... also get rid of `With rst ... End With` and use `Do Until rst.EOF` and `rst.MoveNext`

Comment: @MaddyNikam how if there are 1000 ID?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

1)extract all distinct IDs

2)convert recordset to array

3)Loop through array for each ID

4)save to PDF

**Not tested**

```
    Private Sub PDF_Click()
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim OutputFile As String
    Dim FileSavePath As String
    Dim vArray As Variant
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT distinct ID FROM Report_Query ORDER BY ID")
    With rst
        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst
        vArray = .GetRows(.RecordCount)
    End With
    For Each ID In vArray
       FileSavePath = "C:\Test\" & Format(ID, "000000") & ".pdf"
    ' execute Query here
    '("select * from Report_Query where ID = " & ID )
    'save recordset in PDF format here
    Next ID
    End Sub
```